# How to test checkout with Sagepay?

Tags: checkout, sagepay

I'm trying to test checkout with Sagepay but always get error:

> " CheckPassword: Request failed. Number of failed logins:0"

I'm using Saferpay Business module, version 1.0.12.

I think it is because of my VISA card information but I don't know how to test checkout with Sagepay. Can someone know about that please ?

Comment: I think you should list here the method implemented in your store, or name of the module through which you are connecting to SagePay. From that you wrote I assume that you have some settings not finished. First of all test payments in Sagepay testing (sandbox) mode. Test credit cards numbers you can find here: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm Thanks

Comment: I'm using Saferpay Business module, version 1.0.12.

Comment: Does it happens only with Saferpay Visa? Does other Saferpat methods work?

Comment: Can you please check that you have correct password insert in Magento? There is good chance that you left test password there. 

Make sure you don’t have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I added my configuration to my question. I entered the sagepay test account here.

Comment: @HungDQ : remove those images... dont disclose your valid credentialsssss !!!!!!

Comment: Oh yes, I'm forgotted that. Thank you Tomy.

Comment: I see.. I think at this time your should request support from Saferplay devs. Since you have the password already in your config.